# The Radon-Nikodym derivative for a sequence of dependent variables

Tags: numeraire, radon-nikodym

Suppose that a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ is given. Let $W=\{W_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ be a sequence of $\mathbb{P}$-i.i.d real-valued random variables on $\Omega$. Furthermore, assume that $\mathbb{Q}$ be a new probablity measure on $\Sigma$, and $W$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-i.i.d and that $\mathbb{Q}_{W_1} \sim \mathbb{P}_{W_1}$. We denote by $\mathcal{F}^{W} = \{\mathcal{F}_n^W\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ the natural filtration of $W$. Then, one can say that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$ and for all $D\in \mathcal{F}_n^W = \sigma(W_1, W_2, .., W_n)$
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Q}(D) = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\Big[I_D \prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{d\mathbb{Q}_{W_1}}{d\mathbb{P}_{W_1}}(W_j)\Big]
\end{equation}
or equivalently,
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\Big|_{\mathcal{F}_n^W} = \prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{d\mathbb{Q}_{W_1}}{d\mathbb{P}_{W_1}}(W_j)
\end{equation}
Now, my question is what if $W_j's$ is not independent. In this case, how does the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\Big|_{\mathcal{F}_n^W}$ look like?